# YUI3 Get children of a element

Tags: dom, yui, yui3

I'm trying to get all children of a YUI3 Element like this

```
Y.one(document.body).children 
// results in undefined
```

But I see a **children** attribute here: https://clarle.github.io/yui3/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#attr_children

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get [YUI attributes](https://clarle.github.io/yui3/yui/docs/attribute/), you need to call the [`#get` method](https://clarle.github.io/yui3/yui/docs/api/classes/Node.html#method_get) for that attribute:

```
Y.one(document.body).get('children');
```

Runnable example:

```js
YUI().use('node', function(Y) {
  console.log(Y.one(document.body).get('children'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/0214fdc4cccaa77d6e504320cf70a571/raw/63d260364730fb067f103c00862c7e65685256df/yui-3.18.1_build_yui_yui-min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper" class="yui3-skin-sam">
</div>
```